# Dynamically named WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to make webviews automatically showing pages from assets driectory, based on the page number.
I would like to make webView1 on the first page, webView2 on second, etc, instead of webView. Is there some way to make the webView name dynamically, so I can call it something like {"Webview"+pageNr}?

```
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            String pageNr=Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
            WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());
            switch (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 0: webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/welcome.htm");
                case 1: webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/basic.htm");
            }
            return webView;
        }
```

Comment: Use an array or a list of Strings (for each url).

Comment: @yDelouis I would do that, but whatever I set to the webView is set to all others on all the pages. That why I think the webView should have different name for each page and I would like to have it named depending on the pagenumber.

Comment: Use an array of Webview so. They will be "named" webViews[i].

Comment: actually it works like it is, only I replaced the switch part with if (pageNr==1) {webView.loadUrl....} if (pageNr==2) {.....   strange, but it works and loads different pages onto different pages on the horizontal slide-controlled design

Comment: It was because you forgot to add the line `break;` at the end of your `case` block. So for the value x, the block `case x` and the next blocks `case` are executed.